# How to report how many leads I sent to Salesforce through a Journey in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, reporting, leads

I need to know how many leads in my Sales CLoud instance were created by a "Create Lead Activity" in a Journey in Marketing Cloud.

I'm looking for it in Marketing Cloud reports but I can't find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [journey history](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_history.htm&type=5) feature to extract the contacts list who are injected into the "Create Lead Activity". The limitation in this way is that the view only displays the maximum last 30 days of activity.

From the Journey UI, click on Journey History

[image]

And then click on the Funnel icon and from there you can filter out by Activity = 'salescloudactivity' and Status = 'Complete'

[image]

Finally, you can download the table result as a CSV file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no report like this out of the box in SFMC that will allow you to get all historical data.

You can try build something like this, but the complexity here would depend on the report you want to build.

**Detailed report**

If you want a detailed breakdown on how many leads were created by each journey, you would need to try working with the SFMC API and an [undocumented journey history endpoint](https://gortonington.com/journey-history-for-last-30-days-via-api/). This might be a lot of development to gather the data with SSJS and later aggregate with SQL/Excel.

You might not be able to retrieve all of the historical records this way.

**Created record count only**

If you only want the count of created leads, there is a much simpler way for doing this with SQL queries in SFMC (assuming you have the Lead object as a synchronized data extension).

When a record is created by SFMC in Sales Cloud, the ID of the SFMC connector user on the SF-side (something like `00550M3TH1NgR4ND0M`) will be visible in the `CreatedById` on the object.

You need to identify what's the SF User ID of the user connecting to SFMC and then you can just run the following query:

```sql
Select
    Count(id)
From
    Lead_Salesforce
Where
    CreatedById = '[SFUserID]'
```

Just note this won't allow to differentiate from records created with Ampscript and with the Journey Builder activity.